# How to print a message to user in Razor Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I am creating a web app with Razor Pages and I'm running into an issue. I am trying to send a message to the user when an exception is thrown. I'm imagining something similar to MessageBox class from System.Windows.Forms. Any ideas on whether this is possible or how to do it? Any help is appreciated.

```
try
{
    double oneone = Convert.ToDouble(Project.projectServicesCost);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    //Throw message to user saying projectServicesCost is not in the correct 
    //format and therefore couldn't convert to double
}
```

Here's an example from my code.

Comment: Hi iidrag, thank you for your question. Please edit your question to provide more information about your issue: copy the exception and the code where it occurs, for starters. Try to remember, we can't see your environment, so you need to tell us about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use some library like `NToastNotify`.

You can follow the below steps to implement it:

1.Install NToastNotify package using Package Console Manager:

```
Install-Package NToastNotify
```

2.Configure NToastNotify service and

```
services.AddRazorPages().AddNToastNotifyNoty();
```

3.Add the middlware:

```
app.UseNToastNotify();
```

4.Add the view in _Layout page:

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("NToastNotify")
```

5.Dependency injection IToastNotification then you can use it

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly ILogger<IndexModel> _logger;
    private readonly IToastNotification _toastNotification;

    public IndexModel(ILogger<IndexModel> logger, IToastNotification toastNotification)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _toastNotification = toastNotification;
    }

    public void OnGet()
    {
        try
        {
            throw new NullReferenceException();
        }
        catch
        {
            _toastNotification.AddErrorToastMessage("Some Error Message");
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

For more details, refer to:
https://github.com/nabinked/NToastNotify

Answer (score 0):

You can use modal from Bootstrap and return on a ViewBag the exception and check when is not empty and display the modal

```c#
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(int? id){
  UserViewModel model = new UserViewModel();
  if(id == null){
    ViewBag.Exception = "Please select an ID";
    return View();
  }
  model.User = context.Users.FisrtOrDefault(a => a.id == id);
  return View(model);
}
```

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  var exception = @String.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.Exception).ToString().ToLower();
  if(!exception){
    $("#modal-body").text("@ViewBag.Exception");
    $("#modal").modal("show");
  }
});
</script>
```

Or use alert from js

```js
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var exception = @String.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewBag.Exception).ToString().ToLower();
      if(!exception){
        alert("@ViewBag.Exception");
      }
    });
 </script>
```